# How do I identify connector types?

Tags: identification, connector

[image: I want to identify the connector on right]

I know I can measure the distance between the pins but what to do with the bigger ones? Can anyone point me in the direction of a guide or something idk

Comment: The one on the left is a standard 25-pin d-sub miniature, just look up on mouser.com. The other one is a combo, start with understanding who is the manufacturer. If anything is written on the connector, good. Otherwise, browse, browse, browse.

Comment: https://canada.newark.com/itt-cannon/dbme5w5pk127/d-sub-combo-connector-plug-db/dp/01K2106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one on the left is a DB-25M D-sub connector.

- D = D-sub
- B = shell size
- 25 = number of contacts
- M = male

( https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=d_sub_conn&s=DB-25, my site)

You can buy them here: https://www.digikey.se/short/cmcz3zfr

[image: DB-25M]

{Digikey}

---

The one on the right is a DB-9W4P [D-sub connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature), (aka DB-9W4C):

- D = D-sub
- B = shell size
- 9 = number of contacts
- W = Hybrid
- 4 = 4 cavities for either coax or high current inserts (in your case, high current)
- P = male

(https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=d_sub_conn&s=DB-9W4C, my site)

[image: DB-9W4P]

{Digikey}

You can buy them here: https://www.digikey.se/short/0244p58f

---

> Can anyone point me in the direction of a guide

The wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature

> How do I identify connector types?

Please allow me to point you to my Identiconn connector identification utility: https://connectorbook.com/identification.html.

Comment: Those DB-9W4P connectors on digikey somehow manage to be both more expensive than I would have thought, and cheaper than I would have thought, at the same time. Specialty connector prices almost never seem to make sense.